# Update Query list in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm having a trouble on how can I automatically update my `amount_unpaid` when the time I updated my `amount_paid`column. The result of amount_unpaid should be subtract my `amount` - `amount_paid` = `amount_unpaid` . The way I updated my data is using list like the code below, please check this out, Any help is much appreciated Thanks in advance.

*AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'amount'*

[image]

```
def update_remarks(request):
    product_ids = request.POST.getlist('id[]')
    amt_paid = request.POST.get('amount_paid')

    for id in product_ids:
        unpaid_update = (Person.objects.filter(pk=id).amount - amt_paid) #Error no attribute Amount 
        Person.objects.filter(pk=id).update(amount_paid =  unpaid_update) # this should update every amount_unpaid  based on subtracted amount column
        Person.objects.filter(pk=id).update(amount_paid = amt_paid)
```

Comment: unpaid_update = (Person.objects.filter(pk=id).first().amount - amt_paid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the minimalist solution is:

```
from django.db.models import F

def update_remarks(request):
    product_ids = request.POST.getlist('id[]')
    amt_paid = int(request.POST.get('amount_paid', 0))
    Person.objects.filter(pk__in=product_ids).update(amount_paid=amt_paid, amount_unpaid=F('amount')-amt_paid)
```

I am using `F(<field_name>)` to get the value of the field from that object. Hence I do not need a for loop.

For more information, please see the documentation on [`update(...)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update) and [`F()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions).

Comment: Thanks a lot this is more simple way to do

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `filter` it returns a list of 1 dictionary. For accessing `amount` in that use `Person.objects.filter(pk=id)[0]['amount']`. Or use in this way

```
def update_remarks(request):
    product_ids = request.POST.getlist('id[]')
    amt_paid = request.POST.get('amount_paid')

    for id in product_ids:
        unpaid_update = (Person.objects.get(pk=id).amount - amt_paid) #Error no attribute Amount 
        Person.objects.filter(pk=id).update(amount_paid = amt_paid) # this should update every amount_unpaid  based on subtracted amount column
        Person.objects.filter(pk=id).update(amount_paid = amt_paid)
```